# How do I divide my ionic template in half?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, flexbox

I'm using atm an ion-grid, with ion-cols, works fine for columns, but the problem is a have a table that I would like to fill 50% of the view. Tried setting it like this but doesn't work.

```
ion-grid{
    height: 100%;
}
ion-row.grid1{
    height: 50%;
}
```

This is the my ionic page.html where I want to divide by 2 sections.

```
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row><ion-col col-12><h3>Tijuca</h3></ion-col></ion-row>
       <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-4> <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Sexo:</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col> 
        <ion-col col-4>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label fixed>Data:</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="datetime-local"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label fixed>Convenio:</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="date" value=""></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-12>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Médico solicitante:</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Tel. do Médico:</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Especialidade médica:</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-12>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>HDA:</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
       </ion-row>  
       <ion-row class="grid1">
            <table>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
            <!-- 16x3 table code inside here -->
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Any ideas on what I should be looking for?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Ok done, thats my page.html